# Handling in-application updates on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, joomla, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we are currently moving lots of infrastructure to AWS. Mainly to EC2. Furthermore we are hosting some Joomla applications. Currently our webspace is provided by a simple hosting provider. I would like to move those Joomla applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB). Every customer would get it's own EB application with single instance deployment.

Joomla does have an in-build update functionality. It's pretty easy and updating all our customers is simple because the build-in function takes only a minute to update the installation.

Now I have the following problem: When I'm deploying e.g. Joomla 3.4 via EB and Joomla is publishing version 3.5 I would have to manually update the code (3.4 to 3.5) and upload it via EB to deploy it. Because when I'm using the build-in function the code on the server is changing (3.4 to 3.5) but the code on EB is still the old one (3.4).

Does anyone has expirience with this problem? Thank you in advance.